# RSpec transaction test persists changes to instance variable in before(:each)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

SO...

I have a RSpec testing issue where I am attempting to configure a specific setup (without creating new data, but modifying instance data) and after a test case is ran, the data is not reverted. Please see a simple example below and note that foo is an ActiveRecord object...
    require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe My::Code do
  before(:context) do
    @foo = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
  end

  after(:context) do
    @foo.destroy!
  end

  let(:foo) { @foo.clone }

  describe 'something' do
    # Imagine `something` just returns foo.bar, which is an over-
    # simplification, but gives you an idea of the problem I am seeing
    subject { My::Code.something(foo) }

    context 'when foo has different property value' do
      before(:each) do
        foo.bar = false
      end

      it { is_expected_to be(false) }
    end

    context 'when foo has original property value' do
      # This will fail, as foo's bar property is still false
      it { is_expected_to be(true) }
    end
  end
```

...this is the gist of my situation and I cannot figure out why RSpec is not rolling back. A little of my `rails_helper` file...

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
...
config.around(:each) do |example|
  DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
    example.run
  end
end
```

...any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: If I change my let binding to `let(:foo) { @foo.reload.clone }`, everything works as expected, but it seems I shouldn't need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby on Rails, using [`clone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-clone), this seems to be the expected behavior:

> Identical to Ruby's clone method. This is a “shallow” copy. **Be warned that your attributes are not copied. That means that modifying attributes of the clone will modify the original, since they will both point to the same attributes hash.** If you need a copy of your attributes hash, please use the `dup` method.

emphasis mine. So by using `clone` you are still pointing to the same attributes hash and modifying one modifies the other.

As you have found out, you can `reload` the object which gets rid of all your changes OR you can call [`dup`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup) instead of `clone`:

> Note that this is a “shallow” copy as it copies the object's attributes only, not its associations.